# git create repository with external lib

Tags: git

i have following structure that i need to version control with git (i'm new to git):

> some_path/lib
>
> some_path/htdocs/webroot
>
> some_path/htdocs/projects

the projects dir is a own repository. For the webroot and the lib folder i could make two repositories but i want one repository because when i change things in webroot, i often must change things in Lib and vice versa and so i could have one branch in one repository.

I read about submodules and subtree but it seems that's not the right thing for me because it adds a complexity that i do not really need. I also think about symlinks but i'm not sure if that works fine on windows.

Are there some other Options?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure that this is a desired structure but this is how I would solve it.
You can just make a git repository in the parent folder of "some_path" and have a .gitignore file ignore the whole htdocs/projects folder.
That way you have 2 repos. One Including everything but ignore the projects folder. And another that is just for the projects folder.